# Mobile App backend does not show in existing Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I'm following the procedure to create a Xamarin app with a mobile app backend in Azure.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-preview/

I've create the mobile app in the portal and downloaded the backend runtime and xamarin solutions. When I try to publish the backend runtime, the instructions indicate that the one I just created should show up 'Existing Web Apps'. Mine shows nothing.

My questions are:
1) How can I troubleshoot what shows up in the 'Existing Web Apps'?
2) Is it reasonable to just create a new web app from the VS Publish dialog?
3) If not, where should I place the publish profile that I can download from the azure portal?

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: There's a bug in the Azure SDK 2.7.1 where it is excluding Mobile Apps, and it will be fixed in the next Azure SDK. In the meantime, use the Publish Profile instructions in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. It's appreciated! I'll be looking for to the next Azure SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.a. Ensure you're using the right azure suscription from VS

[image: Review Azure subscriptions]

1.b. Logout and add your subscription login again

[image: Review Azure Account live Id]

2. Yes it's reasonable
3. You can put it wherever you want. From VS website project goto publish settings

[image: project publish options]
4. Then select import

[image] 
5.And Finally browse the publish settings file

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain things clearly. The import of the publishing file worked and seems consistent. I did try logging out and logging back in again and while it showed the correct app on the cloud explorer screen, when I went to publish the solution, the app was not there.

Comment: How did you add the numbers to the screenshots?

Comment: I use TechSmith - Snagit

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with Visual Studio finding the existing apps.  I tend to download the publish settings and use that instead.  This works fine.

Alternatively, create a git repository and check the code into the git repository.  Check out this article for instructions:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Personally, I post my code to a branch of my git repository on GitHub and link the continuous deployment option of the Azure App Service to that.  You can find my blog about this topic here:  http://shellmonger.com/2015/08/29/continuous-deployment-nodejs-and-microsoft-azure/ - it's for NodeJS but the concept and methodology is the same.

Comment: The publish profile works well for me too. Thanks! Also visited your website and I agree the concepts do transfer nicely. Appreciate your time.